# Не выполняется PHP на странице

Tags: php, веб-программирование, perl

На Perl использую модуль HTML::Template;
Выводом странички соответственно занимается Perl-скрипт, большие куски HTML_кода вытягивая из шаблонов.
После вывода основного кода страницы таким образом, подтягиваю и футер:

```
my $html_footer = HTML::Template->new(filename => $file_footer);
print $html_footer->output;
```

Футер - это тоже текстовый файлик-шаблон footer.tmpl
В нем в строке пишу:

```
<div>Copyright © <?php echo date('Y'); ?> All Rights Reserved.</div>
```

Не выполняет, пусто: Copyright © All Rights Reserved.
В .htaccess прописано:

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php .php .htm .html .tmpl
```

Передача через параметр TMPL_VAR NAME тоже не работает. В исходном коде выведенной страницы в браузере так и висит:

```
<div>Copyright © <?php echo date('Y'); ?> All Rights Reserved.</div>
```

В обычных html-страничках PHP отрабатывает, т.е. он подключен и работает.
В чем может быть причина? Спасибо!

Comment: А у вас PHP  настроен на сервере?

Comment: Какие дополнительные настройки нужно сделать? На статических страницах всё работает!

Comment: Так у вас же не файл, а просто строка с PHP кодом. Для файле handler сработал бы, а просто для строки как? Обычно делается же php -r “<?php echo ‘test’; ?>” из консоли чтобы вывести результат.

Comment: perl же на знает, что в этой странице есть php код который должен выполняться интерпретатором php. Единственный путь - допилить вашу систему шаблонов, что бы запускала php и скармливала ему страницу. никакие настройки сервера не помогут. А вообще на ясно, зачем нужен php код, если есть perl

Comment: Понял. Что ступил ) Действительно, Перл же не знает что это строчка для PHP!  Зациклился что то на ПХП вчера. 
Всё сделал. На Perl. Всем спасибо! Тема закрыта.